# Postgresql replace comma from right in position 3 and replace dot and comma left to that position

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

I am having a currency value with comma and dot. I need to change some European style currency to UK style value.

```
11,200.00 -> 11200.00
11.200,00 -> 11200.00
58.20 -> 58.20
58,20 -> 58.20
2500 -> 2500
```

I have tried using right() and replace functions but no luck.

Could anyone please help me in writing replace function to handle this.

Comment: Why do you store numbers in a `text` (or `varchar`)  column? That is a **really**, really bad idea. Do you have a chance to fix that broken design before you proceed?

Comment: The design is like row wise key value pair, each key is of different data type which are stored as string

Comment: It is already in live. Now we encounter the European style currency values coming in.

Comment: A design like that should have never made it into production.

Comment: The question is about parsing of incoming data and not about storing, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *is* an issue in European countries, especially when new and legacy software have to co-exist.
If "European style currency values coming in" from an external source then you have no other choice but handle them. First try to determine which style the string value belongs to with regexp matching and then do the relevant correction. Something like this illustration:

```sql
select case 
 when :strval ~ '^[+-]?(\d+\.)*\d+(,\d+)$' then replace(replace(:strval, '.', ''), ',', '.')
 when :strval ~ '^[+-]?(\d+,)*\d+(\.\d+)$' then replace(:strval, ',', '')
 when :strval ~ '^[+-]?\d+$' then :strval
 -- maybe there are other formats so the list may grow
end;
```

As a function:

```sql
create or replace function unify_numeric_format(strval text)
returns numeric language sql immutable as
$$
select case 
 when strval ~ '^[+-]?(\d+\.)*\d+(,\d+)$' then replace(replace(strval, '.', ''), ',', '.')
 when strval ~ '^[+-]?(\d+,)*\d+(\.\d+)$' then replace(strval, ',', '')
 when strval ~ '^[+-]?\d+$' then strval
 -- maybe there are other formats so the list may grow
end::numeric; 
$$;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with "European style currencies" - this is a problem that needs to be taken into account for any software that should be used in an international context - not just for currencies, but also for date and time values. The **only** correct solution to that problem is to _never_ store formatted values, but to use proper data types, `numeric` for numbers, `date` for dates, `timestamp` for date/time values etc. Then they can be formatted when displayed to any format the user wants

Comment: I fully agree. Separation of content and presentation. Unfortunately there are existing systems that do store formatted values. This is a fact of life. Sometimes these are quite expensive or business critical so they have to talk to proper ones in order to be somehow integrated into the new landscape.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this specific problem, I would make two `replace()` steps:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1cd5839bcbf84f7bf73435a432e2f493)

```
SELECT replace(replace('11.200,00', '.', ''), ',', '.')
```

Nonetheless, you should take the comment of @a_horse_with_no_name serious: Don't store values as a type `text`.

**Edit**: Wait, you have both variants: `11.200,00` **AND** `11,200.00` ? You have to normalize this table. Please switch the column type to `numeric`.